# Cycle though multiple MixRGBs with one value

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

A group of multiple ColorRamps mixed as follow:

[image]

I want to achieve the following:

- By change the value to 1 i switch to the second colorRamp
- value of 2 switch to the third colorRamp
- value of 0 is the first colorRamp

Note: i know that i could just link the first and second MixRGB to the input and control them individually, but i would like to control both of them with one controller if possible.

Comment: I answered your question but I realized that your color ramp don't do anything since their factor is alway 0.5. their output value will always be the color in the middle of the ramp

Comment: Right, i was only trying to demonstrate the problem, now i have it where i want to like so: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17DfM-dHE91f6NnDYmQWh6QE-ASShKAyH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check 'Clamp' on the first one and add a 'Map Range' node between the value and the 'Fac' of the second one. Check clamp on it and set its parameters: 'From Min' to 1, 'From Max' to 2,  'To Min' to 0, 'To Max' to 1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Worked great thanks!

Comment: Neat solution. Hope you don't mind the edits.. so many 'from's and 'to's flying around... reverse if you don't like them.